# JQuery Autocomplete with URL(Provides JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete box (below) having source as a PHP file.

```
$("#autocompleteFrom").autocomplete({
    source: "../wp-content/plugins/plugin-search/js/GetCountry.php",
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#autocompleteFromHidden").val(ui.item.code);
        $("#autocompleteNameFromHidden").val(ui.item.name);
    }
});
```

Now i want to change the source of the autocomplete to a URL which returns a list of locations in JSON format as below.

```
{"currentCulture":null,"airports":[{"code":"BCN","name":"El Prat Airport"},
{"code":"CDG","name":"Paris-Charles De Gaulle"},{"code":"ORY","name":"Paris-
Orly"}],"destinations":null}
```

Please help me on this. Let me if I need to provide more details.

Comment: Click on the "view source" in this page https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Comment: Thanks for the response Adiga, I have gone through a lot of posts already and what I understand is that i need to use some Ajax functions to get it done. I have tried with some of the Ajax functions but it didn't help.I didn't get what I am looking for. I need

Comment: Sorry wrong link. Check this link https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: I tried like this.
source: function(request, response) {
 $.ajax({
 url: "http://***.azurewebsites.net/api/destinations?culturecode=en-GB",
 data: { query: request.term },
 success: function(data) {
 var transformed = $.map(data, function(el) {
                        return {
                            label: el.phrase,
                            id: el.id
                        };
                    });
                    response(transformed);
                },
            });
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a label attribute to the JSON items might solve you're problem. See if this helps:

```js
$( function() { 
    $( "#autocompleteFrom" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
      var search_data = [];
        var data = {"currentCulture":null,"airports":[{"code":"BCN","name":"El Prat Airport"},
{"code":"CDG","name":"Paris-Charles De Gaulle"},{"code":"ORY","name":"Paris-Orly"}],"destinations":null};

          data.airports.map(function(item){
             item.label = item.name;
             search_data.push(item);
          });
          
          response(search_data);
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#autocompleteFromHidden").val(ui.item.code);
        $("#autocompleteNameFromHidden").val(ui.item.name);
      }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="Countries">Countries: </label>
  <input id="autocompleteFrom">
</div>
 
  Result:
  <div class="ui-widget">
  <input type="text" id="autocompleteFromHidden" class="ui-widget-content"/>
  <input type="text" id="autocompleteNameFromHidden" class="ui-widget-content"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Unfortunately its not working in my data structure. Please find my JSON structure.

Comment: {"currentCulture":null,"airports":[{"code":"BCN","name":"El Prat Airport"},
{"code":"CDG","name":"Paris-Charles De Gaulle"},{"code":"ORY","name":"Paris-
Orly"}],"destinations":null}

Comment: I have edited the answer to have your json as the data source.

Comment: That was fantastic maxuville. For my learning purpose It would be great if you could explain something about these two steps.
data.airports.map(function(item){
       item.label = item.name;
       search_data.push(item);
I was doing below steps. $(value.destinations).each(function(index, value) { console.log(index); console.log(value); if ((value.name.toLowerCase()).indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) != -1) { console.log(value); search_data.push(value.name); } })
In this step I was not able to access the 'code' and 'name' properties later. Could you tell me the difference please.

Comment: The airports object is the array with all the data you needed. So I added the label member in each item from the airports object and copied it into a new object. The new object now had all the data for searching and also for displaying on the two other inputs which is done by the 'select' option.

Answer (score 0):

set your source as serviceUrl like below

```
$("#autocompleteFrom").autocomplete({
serviceUrl: "../wp-content/plugins/plugin-search/js/GetCountry.php",
onSelect: function(ui) {
    $("#autocompleteFromHidden").val(ui.item.code);
    $("#autocompleteNameFromHidden").val(ui.item.name);
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that didn't help.
URL is holding data in JSON format as mentioned in the question.